# Concerning latest update and asset browser

Tags: add-on

I want to upgrade my blender from version 3.0 to version 3.3 and I’m concerned if I’ll lose all my saved assets or I’ll have to reinstall everything from scratch after updating.

Is there any way I can upgrade my blender without losing my assets or having to reinstall them all over again and moreover, how to keep old settings and addons?

Comment: When you start a new Blender version for the first time, you have the option to copy the settings of the old version. All addons and settings will be copied.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment @quellenform but can you please take me on a tour on how to upgrade, my reasons is because I had watch a video on YouTube concerning blender updating and it’s says I’m to uninstall current version of blender before installing updated version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, then all settings and addons are stored in the path `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\`.

When you start *Blender 3.3* for the first time, you will see a welcome screen where you have the option to copy the settings from a previously installed version (in this screenshot I had *Blender 3.2* installed before):

[image]

Just click on "Load 3.x Settings" in the lower left corner.

Your settings and addon will be copied and saved in the path `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\`.

The settings of the old version remain untouched.

You don't have to uninstall the old version either, because you can use both versions. Uninstalling the old version is not necessary, but advisable if you don't want to use the old version at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the further explanation...well I’d like to uninstall the old version so as to save storage.I will try this out and drop and feedback.

Comment: hello...thank for the help...everything seems okay now, I went ahead and installed the new version and followed the steps you provided all my assets,add-ons and setting all available.
I haven't deleted the previous version, but I would later.

Comment: @Gad You are welcome!

Comment: @Gad If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.